# TF53001: The database operation was canceled by an administrator. TFS 2017 + Sql 2016

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I installed TFS 2017 Update 1 RC (15.112.26206.0 (Tfs2017.Update1.RC2).
I updated my sql to Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)   Oct 28 2016 18:17:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor) .

I changed the sql compatibility to the diferents options and i still have the same error.

Comment: Under what circumstances are you getting that error message?

Comment: When did you get that error message?

Comment: Vote to close due to Release Candidate which is long gone and no feedback from OP.